# How many object will be alive after executing the last 3 lines?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

I have just started learning Java and got stuck with understanding of this problem. In the code below, how many objects will be alive after executing the last 3 lines?

```
public class Demo {
    Demo obj;

    void show() {
        System.out.println("Hello this is show method.");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Demo obj1 = new Demo();
        Demo obj2 = new Demo();
        Demo obj3 = new Demo();
        Demo obj4 = new Demo();
        obj1.obj = obj2;
        obj2.obj = obj3;
        obj3.obj = obj4;
        obj4.obj = obj1;

        obj1 = null;
        obj2 = null;
        obj3 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you walk us through what you think the answer is and why ?  Then we may give you an detailed explanation. I believe the answer is 4 +1 if we count String args[].  all references are kept because of *.obj=...

Answer (score 0):

If by "alive" you mean "not eligible for garbage collection", all 4 objects will be "alive" after the last line is executed.

`obj4` would still contain a reference to the last `Demo` instance created (`Demo obj4 = new Demo()`). That instance would hold a reference to the 1st `Demo` instance (due to `obj4.obj = obj1;`), which would hold a reference to the 2nd `Demo` instance (due to `obj1.obj = obj2;`), which would hold a reference to the 3rd `Demo` instance (due to `obj2.obj = obj3;`).

Therefore all 4 objects would still have references, and cannot be garbage collected after the last 3 statements are executed.

Comment: Quibble.  After the final statement, there are no statements that could use `obj4`.  That means that the variable itself can no longer influence the execution and it *could* be treated as unreachable.  Whether the GC does this is implementation dependent.

Comment: @StephenC I guess you can always say that when the main method terminates, all the objects it instantiated can be garbage collected. I answered the question as if it asks about the state of the program just after the `obj3 = null;` assignment, without taking into account that the program ends after that statement.

Comment: This applies to any method, not just `main`.  And it also applies within a method ... if a local variable is not used after a particular point in the method.  My point is that it is NOT as simple as you think / your answer implies.